# Why is my cactus turning purple and pale?

Tags: diagnosis, cactus

Ever since I got this cactus it has been growing, but now it's becoming purple and paler. What am I doing wrong, and how do I solve it? I'm rather new at this gardening stuff so help would really be appreciated.

I already tried watering it less but it's still worsening. What other things should I try?

Edit: I live in south east asia and had it for 4 weeks now. The beads of moisture is water and its indoors on a windowstill [image]

Comment: Need a better pic with the light behind or above you rather than  against a window providing light  to the front of the plant, hard to see any detail in this photo, not even sure what it is. What part of the world are you in and how long have you had the plant?

Comment: Actually, I've just noticed what appear to be beads of moisture or other clear substance at the top on the right hand branch - is it water or something else? And is it indoors on a windowsill, or outdoors?

Comment: Can you make the picture brighter, because it looks dark green to me?

Comment: When you say its turning purple, are you referring to the dark streaks all over the plant, or were they there originally? What kind of soil is it potted into and how often were you watering it originally, and how much did you reduce it?

Comment: @Bamboo Yes the dark streaks all across the plant. The soil is soil i got near the burning grounds in my house for fertilizer. I used to water it twice a day now its gone to twice a week

Answer (score 2):

The worst thing is, I can't decide which cactus this actually is - I'm inclining towards possibly a Euphorbia of some description, or more likely Orbea tubiflora maybe, but I really am not sure. Even so, there are some things you can try - first, can you get hold of some sterilised potting compost rather than just garden soil? It needs a sandy or gritty free draining potting medium as soon as possible, and a pot with drainage holes in the bottom if that one doesn't have them - in the meantime, and ongoing, stop watering, you're watering way too much. I don't know what part of the world you're in, but most cactus can go weeks without any water at all, particularly during the winter months, when they should be watered very sparingly occasionally just to prevent shrivelling. I wouldn't suggest you water it at all at this stage for at least a month, and then see how its doing - even when you do start watering, just a little maybe every two weeks, or less often if its winter where you are.

The purple streaks may mean its already too late and a fungal infection or rot has already set in and the plant will just die, but if you want to try and save it, follow the advice given above. In the meantime, I will spend more time researching what plant it could actually be... if its one of the Orbeas, they are at real risk of rot if watered too much from autumn through winter, though they need more water once spring arrives, at which time, rot should not occur.